# Accessing a secondary relationship from primary model without intermediate table with foreign keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have this structure:

```
model: OrderItem
belongsTo ProductInfo

model: ProductInfo
hasMany OrderItem
hasMany Barcode

model: Barcode
belongsTo ProductInfo
```

How can I make an easy accessible relationship in the OrderItem to get the Barcodes that match the same product_info_id? The product_infos table is of course not a classic intermediate table containing the foreign keys.

I know this is probably a very simple question since the relationship is also very basic, but I'm kind of confused with all the answers I find online and in the Laravel docs for slightly different situations. F.e. hasManyThrough is not working out in any way here.

Answer (score 0):

This relationship is correct you can access barcode like

```
$order->ProductInfo->barcodes
```

This will return an array of barcodes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pivot model, try this.

`OrderItem belongs to many Barcode`

Then the `Barcode` model,

`table: barcodes`
`Barcode belongs to many OrderItem`

And last create a `pivot table`
`php artisan make:migration create_barcodes_order_items_table` and make two columns for `foreign_id`s, `order_item_id` and `barcode_id`.

It would automatically take care of your relationship unless you didn't do anything outside the pattern.

Then you can get all barcodes of order and all orders for a barcode.
`$order->barcodes`

Comment: I know I could create a pivot table and do it in that way, but it seems kind of redundant / overcomplicating things if I already have a column in both models (product_info_id) where the value is always the same if the models are related. The relation is in that way obvious to us humans, but not so easy to make obvious to Laravel it seems.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I saw like many to many relationship. But it is not.

`$order->ProductInfo->barcodes` is enough. Nothing want to change.